# NoReverseMatch 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<id>\\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\\w]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Django, using version 2.0. Started building a 'shop' application according to the 'Django by Example' book. But the book uses django version 1.8.
The problem is, when I browse http://127.0.0.1:8000/ this error appears:

"NoReverseMatch at/
Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '(None, 'alpina')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P\d+)/(?P[-\w]+)/$']".

'alpina' is the product's name which I added from admin site.

**Here is urls.py of my app:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name='shop'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.product_list,
        name='product_list_by_category'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.product_detail,
        name='product_detail'),
]
```

**Here is the models.py of my app:**

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField( max_length=200,
                             db_index=True )
    slug = models.SlugField( max_length=200,
                             db_index=True,
                             unique=True )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse( 'shop:product_list_by_category',
                        args=[self.slug] )

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey( Category,
                                  related_name='products',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE
                                  )
    name = models.CharField( max_length=200, db_index=True )
    slug = models.SlugField( max_length=200, db_index=True )
    image = models.ImageField( upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d',
                               blank=True )
    description = models.TextField( blank=True )
    price = models.DecimalField( max_digits=10, decimal_places=2 )
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField( default=True )
    created = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True )
    updated = models.DateTimeField( auto_now=True )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__( *args, **kwargs )
        self.id = None

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse( 'shop:product_detail',
                        args=[self.id, self.slug] )
```

**Here is my views.py of my project:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category, Product

def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/list.html',
                  {'category': category,
                   'categories': categories,
                   'products': products})

def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,
                                id=id,
                                slug=slug,
                                available=True)
    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/detail.html',
                  {'product': product})
```

**Here is my urls.py of my project:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove this from your product model

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__( *args, **kwargs )
            self.id = None
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working after removing this.